# How do I make a private network (like a hotspot) that has a Express server running on it?

Tags: node.js, express, hotspot

I have recently been working on a LAN file sharing site (to upload files from your phone to your computer, vice-verca) but it doesn't work offline as it needs a private IP run on which requires a Wi-Fi network.

So, I was hoping to make a private hotspot (on a computer) via NodeJS which can run the ExpressJS server on.

How do I do this?

Comment: Node is not a router, it only receives and parses the traffic it is sent. You're looking to build your own network, what you do with it is up to you.

Comment: Post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Node is not a router, it only receives and parses the traffic it is sent. You're looking to build your own network, what you do with it is up to you.